# What is a proper symmetrization procedure for polynomial k.p. Hamiltonians in magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, second-quantization

Suppose we find a polynomial approximation of a Hamiltonian in two-dimensional crystal around some point in momentum space to have the form $H=k_x^n k_y^m$, with $n \neq m$. After adding magnetic field, one uses replacement of momentum operators to non-commuting canonical momentum operators $k_x\to\Pi_x$ and $k_y\to\Pi_y$. After such substitution the original Hamiltonian $\Pi_x^n \Pi_y^m$ is no longer a Hermitian operator and requires symmetrization. What is the proper way to perform such symmetrization and is there a criteria to unique define such operation after gauge is fixed?

As an example, what would be the difference between taking Hamiltonian as $H=\frac{1}{2}(\Pi_x^n \Pi_y^m + \Pi_y^m \Pi_x^n)$ or selecting it in the Weyl quantization form with average of all possible polynomial orderings of $\Pi_x$ and $\Pi_y$ - e.g. $H\sim(\Pi_x^n \Pi_y^m + \Pi_x^{n-1} \Pi_y^m \Pi_x + \Pi_x^{n-2} \Pi_y^m \Pi_x^2+ \dots)$?